# Does there exists simple graph for this given condition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Does there exist a simple graph whose edge-chromatic number is 5, but if we delete the edges of a Hamilton cycle from it then the edge-chromatic number of the graph obtained is only 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here's an example;

[image]

This graph has $7$ vertices and $13$ edges. Each color class is a matching, so it can contain at most $3$ edges, and therefore we need at least $\lceil \frac{13}{3} \rceil = 5$ colors.

However, deleting the highlighted Hamiltonian cycle leaves a graph which is a $6$-cycle with an isolated vertex, and that has an edge coloring with only $2$ colors.

(The construction is motivated by Theorem 1 in Beineke and Wilson's [*On the edge-chromatic number of a graph*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(73)90023-X), which gives a simple condition guaranteeing that a graph is class 2.)